# Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как в figma изображение без текста экспортировать?

Tags: css, figma

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как в figma изображение без текста экспортировать?

Comment: слой с текстом скрыть а слой с изображением выделить и экспортировать как ...

Comment: Не обязательно что-то скрывать, просто ткнуть в слой с изображением. Если в группе, то предварительно разгруппировать